# Adding a a tracking pixel to my ecommerce cart

Tags: javascript

This site is probably overkill for the level of technical input I need for my query but the only other option is to ask Weebly support who are useless.

Essentially I have a tracking pixel from google to see when people have through adverts and bought something on our site.
However, the way you have to edit the site through Weebly's editor means that when you put the tracking pixel in, it is encoded with

```
<script type="html/template" id="tracking-pixel-receipt_page">
```

But the tracking pixel is itself a script:

```
<script type="html/template" id="tracking-pixel-receipt_page">
&lt;!-- Google Code for Made a Sale Conversion Page --&gt;
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
/* &lt;![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 11111111;
var google_conversion_language = &quot;en&quot;;
var google_conversion_format = &quot;1&quot;;
var google_conversion_color = &quot;ffffff&quot;;
var google_conversion_label = &quot;ryOQCOuHhF0Q9tbjyAM&quot;;
var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]&gt; */
&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;    //www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js&quot;&gt;
&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;noscript&gt;
&lt;div style=&quot;display:inline;&quot;&gt;
&lt;img height=&quot;1&quot; width=&quot;1&quot; style=&quot;border-style:none;&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; src=&quot;//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/957934454/?label=ryOQCOuHhF0Q9tbjyAM&amp;amp;guid=ON&amp;amp;script=0&quot;/&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/noscript&gt;
</script>
```

So as you can see it comes encoded as HTML when I look at my site.
Because you can't get in there and edit on Weebly to type="text/javascript", I just wanted to ask you guys who I can get the tracking pixel to work with the script that Weebly forces it into.

Maybe this is very simple, but I have no experience with these things beyond basic HTML so forgive my ignorance.

Thanks for your assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you could try.

1. See if the Weebly editor has a button for adding raw input or disabling the automatic encoding.
2. See if Weebly gives you direct access to the site header and footer file.
3. Contact Weebly and ask them to put the raw code in your site's footer.

Comment: Unfortunately it is impossible to edit the raw data on on the cart and checkout pages. It is possible to put code in the headers and footers, but again not for the cart and checkout pages. This needs to appear only on the receipt page so I can tell when a customer has made a sale. Weebly have got back to me saying just remove the <script> tags around the code but I don't think this will help :(

Comment: The problem is that things like <> characters are being shown as &lt;

Comment: Not really sure what else to recommend in that case, sorry :( Try removing the <script> tags and see if it works :P

Comment: I ended up doing a work-around, by using google tag manager and getting it to trigger the tracking pixel everytime the receipt page is viewed.